# Development of imaginary exponent without appealing to "ambiguity" between $i$ and $-i$

Tags: exponentiation, exponential-function, complex-numbers

Is there a way to develop the definition of the imaginary exponent, $z^i$, for complex $z$, that does not appeal to the notion that $i$ and $-i$ are "qualitatively indistinct" and that does not rely on *defining* $a^b = e^{b\log{a}}$ using a pre-defined exponentiation function?

My motivation is that I would like to be able to develop complex exponentiation in a "natural" way, in a sequence like:

1. $z^n = z * z \cdots * z$, $n$ times for $n\in\mathbb{N}$
2. $\sqrt[m]{z}$ is the non-negative real $y$ such that $y^m = z$.
3. For rational $q = n/m$, $z^{n/m} = \sqrt[m]{z^n}$.
4. For $r\in\mathbb{R}$, $z^r = \lim_{q->r}{z^q}$, where $q$ is rational.
5. $z^i$ is "something."

Finally, the usual rules for dealing with products and sums in the exponent allow us to evaluate $z^w$ for complex $z$ and $w$.

The payoff for this development is that $e$ could be "discovered" as the answer to the question: For which positive real number, $a$, does $f_a(\theta) = a^{i \theta}$ traverse the unit circle at just the right speed so that the period of $f_a$ is the circumference of the circle?  And the connection between $e^{i \theta}$ and the trigonometric functions follows intuitively from there.

The way I've seen complex exponentiation developed before fall into two categories:

1. The exponential function is simply *defined* as $\exp{z} = \sum{ z^k/k!}$, and the fact that this function happens to behave on suitable inputs just like taking powers of $e$ might be interpreted as a convenient miracle.
2. The fact that $i$ and $-i$ are equally valid solutions to $x^2 = -1$ is invoked to "prove" that $z^i$ lies on the unit circle, some hand waving about approximating $z^{s i}$ for small $s$ occurs, and that approximation is used to build up a full definition.  The problem is that the whole argument hinges on the ambiguity between $i$ and $-i$ when $i$ is defined as "the" solution to $x^2 = -1$.  If the complex numbers are developed more carefully, so $i$ is merely the (unambiguous) pair $(0, 1)$, then the argument can't be developed.  Besides, $z^i$ *doesn't* lie on the unit circle for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$.

So is there a more natural (yet rigorous) way to develop $z^i$?

Comment: The «ambiguity» you refer to is simply the fact that $(-1)^2=1$. What exactly does not referring to that even mean?

Comment: The ambiguity is in defining $i$ as "the" solution to an equation that has two solutions.  I'm not satisfied with the argument here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9770/understanding-imaginary-exponents, which is based on the development here: http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_22.html#Ch22-S5, and both use the ambiguity to argue that $z^{-i} = (z^i)^*$.

Comment: The point 2. requires $z$ to be REAL, no? More generally, you might want to make more precise where in your post you assume that $z$ is real (positive) and where you do not.

Comment: No, one does not define $i$ to be «the» solution to the equation but «a» solution. The first would indeed be ambiguous, and that is precisely why we don't do it.

Comment: I don't see how you plan to continue after defining $z^i$: how will you define $z^{ir}$ for real $r$?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez If you read the linked answer and document you'll see what I'm getting at.  The argument goes: $i$ and $-i$ are equally valid imaginary units, so any valid expression involving $i$ is equally valid if we replace all the $i$'s with $-i$.  So if $z^i = x + i y$ then $z^{-i} = x - i y$ and $1 = z^i z^{-i} = (x + i y)(x - i y) = x^2 + y^2$ so $z^i$ is on the unit circle.  And it's just not *true*.  Take $z = -1$ for example.

Comment: The problem with that is more in assuming that the symmetry between $i$ and $-i$ will extend to every context.

Comment: A much simpler instance of the problem mentioned in my last comment is that from $\Re(i)>0$ you cannot conclude that $\Re(-i)>0$.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez I think I'm still missing something.  What's the context that justifies the $z^{-i} = x - i y$ step?  I can see that the formula is "true" when $z$ is a positive real number, but then I'm relying on a pre-existing definition for complex exponentiation.  The conditions under which it's valid to substitute $-i$ for every instance of $i$ in an expression need to be developed carefully, right?  I was hoping complex exponentiation could be developed without relying on that substitution.

Comment: The difficulty is that there are many extensions of the $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ function $x\mapsto a^x$ to a $\mathbb C\to\mathbb C$ function, even if we require the extension to satisfy $a^{w+z}=a^wa^z$.  The assumption that $a^{\overline z}=\overline{a^z}$ picks out a particularly nice family of extensions.  That is, this condition is not *provable*, but is *imposed*.  My [answer to a similar question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/542533/21467) has more details.

Comment: @StevenTaschuk Thanks for the comment, Steven.  I'd love to read the similar question and answer, but the link you posted goes to this same question.

Comment: Sorry, I'm klutzing my links today.  It was supposed to be: my [answer to a similar question](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/834572/21467).