# Why is e used for polar form of complex numbers?

Tags: complex-numbers, polar-coordinates

This is a real basic question.

Why is $e$ the base for polar form of complex numbers?

In high school maths I learned that e is useful in derivatives etc. And it's conventional to use it for exponential growth/decay functions, although really we could use any base number for them if we tweak the exponent appropriately (eg. $Ae^t = Ax^{kt})$ for appropriate values of x and k).

So could any number be used as the base for polar form of complex numbers? Is $e$ just convention or is there some special relationship to $i$ that makes this work?

Comment: This actually came up recently, [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1233283/why-did-euler-use-e-to-represent-complex-numbers). I think Michael's [answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1233316/120540) hit the nail on the head, personally.

Comment: Thanks that other question answers it in detail.