# Understanding $e$ and $e$ to the power of imaginary number

Tags: complex-analysis

How did the value of $e$ come from compound interest equation. What does the value of $e$ really mean...

Capacitors and inductors charge and discharge exponentially, radioactive elements decay exponentially and even bacterial growth follows exponential i.e., $(2.71)^x$ ,why can't it be $2^x$ or something.

Also $e^2$ means $e*e$ ,$e^3$ means $e*e*e$
But what exactly $e^{ix}$ mean...

I want to know how to visualise $e^{i \pi} =-1 $in graphs... I knw how to get the value of such type of equations but Im not able to understand what they actually mean....
Plz help me...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to prove Euler's formula: $e^{it}=\cos t +i\sin t$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3510/how-to-prove-eulers-formula-eit-cos-t-i-sin-t) (but maybe not quite a duplicate, so I retracted my close vote)

Comment: Compare this question to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/37052/prove-ei-pi-1?lq=1 (which likewise was marked as a duplicate, but does not ask how to visualize the equation)

Comment: What do you mean by "visualize $e^{i\pi} = -1$ in a graph"? What do you mean by "how to get the value of such type of equations"? Perhaps if you _show_ how to get the value, showing what you actually _do_ understand about $e$, it would be clearer to us what you do _not_ understand about $e$, which would help us explain it.

Comment: In general, bacteria growth and radioactive decay do _not_ go as $e^x$ unless you choose the units of $x$ very carefully. And it just as easily _can_ be $2^x$; you just need to make a slightly different choice of units. Why do you say it must be $e^x$ and not $2^x$?

Comment: For the intuition part, I like to think of $e^{i\theta}$ [as a rotation operator](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1242825/explain-why-ei-pi-1-to-an-8th-grader/1293700#1293700) on complex numbers.

Comment: [You're that guy on the right, huh?](http://xkcd.com/179/)

Answer (score 5):

There are many properties that make the exponential function special; one that I find particularly instructive is:

> There is **exactly one function $f$** such that $f'(x)=f(x)$ for all $x$ and $f(0)=1$. This function is the *exponential function*, and it turns out that there is a particular real number $e$ such that $f(a)=e^a$ whenever $a\in \mathbb Q$. Therefore it makes sense to use the notation $e^x$ for $f(x)$ for *all* $x$.

The property $f'(x)=f(x)$ is what makes this particular exponential function useful for describing exponential growth and decay, because it makes it easy to relate the *instantaneous rate of change* to the current size of the thing that is growing or decaying.

In the complex plane it so happens that $f(ix)$ will be a point $x$ radians counterclockwise along the unit circle. This is forced by the relation $f'(x)=f(x)$, though it doesn't have any particular intuitive relation to repeated multiplication. One just has to get used to the fact that *the* unique function that obeys the nice rules we know from the real exponential happens to behave that way for complex arguments.

Answer (score 1):

$e^{i\pi}$ is a point in the complex plane. You get this point if you "walk" $\pi$ radiants on the unit circle. This point turns out to be $(-1,0)$ or expressed in complex numbers $-1+0\cdot i$.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Henning's answer.

If the exponential function $\exp(x) := e^x$ 
satisfies $\exp'(x) = \exp(x)$, then by the chain rule it also satisfies $\frac{d}{dx}\big(\exp(ax)\big) = a\exp(ax)$.

Check that the complex-valued function
$$
\phi(x) := \cos(x)+i\sin(x)
$$
satisfies $\phi'(x) = i\phi(x)$.  And $\phi(0)=1$.  Therefore $\phi(x) = \exp(i x)$.  That is:
$$
e^{ix} = \cos x + i \sin x
$$

Answer (score 1):

> How did the value of e come from compound interest equation.

[Compound interest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_interest#Compound_Interest) is when previously earned interest earns interest.

$$S=P\left(1+\frac{r}{n} \right)^{nt}$$

where

> S = value after t periods
>
> P = principal amount (initial investment)
>
> r = annual nominal interest rate (not reflecting the compounding)
>
> **n = number of times the interest is compounded per year**
>
> t = number of years the money is borrowed for

Look at $n$. If $n=4$ you only get money 4 times year from the compound.
Let's say $n=12$ so you'd get your compound interest every month. That kind of makes sense if you also get your loan on a monthly basis.

Could there be a sweeter sound than money coming in at the beginning of every month? Actually, yes. What if you could get the compound money on a daily basis? It wouldn't be much, but you'd get money **every day**.

What you say? You want it every hour? Minute? OK! Fine, you know what? You can have it as a constant incoming stream of money. Are you happy now?

What would that mean for $n$? The number increases from 4, to 12 (month), 356 (day), 8544 (hour), ...up to $\infty$. That's exactly the definition of $e$: let $n$ go to infinity.

$$e^x=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{x}{n} \right)^{n}$$

Which is exactly why the formula for [continuous interest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_interest#Continuous_compounding) looks the way it does (I tried to stay conistent with variable names).

$$S=P\underbrace{\left(1+\frac{r}{n} \right)^{nt}}_{e^{rt}}=Pe^{rt}$$

> What does the value of e really mean

For the interest example, $e$ means *to do it continuously*. Such values are often not immediately sound. But other statistical values aren't either, like the average for example:

The birthrate in the US (2012) is 1.88 So eeeer every woman gets *almost* 2 children? Or is ever second child missing an arm? This number makes no sense when thinking of it as a value like an amount of children. That's because it isn't an amount. It's an average amount.

The same goes for $e$. Given the different properties of interests, it can be hard to compare them. With $e$, there's a common ground. Instead of asking how much money you get how often per year, the question now boils down to "How much money do you get *at the moment*?".

> Capacitors and inductors charge and discharge exponentially, radioactive elements decay exponentially and even bacterial growth follows exponential i.e., $2.71^x$ ,why can't it be $2^x$ or something.

It actually can be. But it's hard to compare exponential growths that have a different base. It's good to have a common base.

Now why is that base $e$?

It has to do with the physics. A lot of the principles of our world can be described with differential equations.

Some such equations can look something like

$$0=a\dddot y + b\ddot y +...$$

and without going into any detail, the solution for $y$ can look like

$$y(t) = C_1e^{\lambda_1t} + C_2e^{\lambda_2t}+...$$

This is because the derivative of $e^x$ is again $e^x$.
The *derivative* plays an important role when dealing with *differential* equations, which is why $e^x$ shows up in the general solution.

Answer (score 0):

There is actually no particular reason why exponential growth must be
expressed as a power of $e$.
In the example of radioactive decay, for example, we often speak of
the *half-life* of a radioactive isotope, which is the amount of time
that it takes for half of the atoms in a sample to decay.
Thus if the half-life of an isotope is $H$ years, the portion of the sample
that will remain after $t$ years is $2^{t/H}$ —a power of $2$,
*not* expressed as a power of $e$.

Likewise, in finance there are things such as the "rule of $70$"
for estimating the amount of time it will take for an amount of money
to double at compound interest. If the result of the rule of $70$ is
$D$ years, and you leave $P$ dollars in an account at the same rate
of compound interest for $t$ years, the rule of $70$ says
you have $P \times 2^{t/D}$ dollars in the account at the end.
Again, a power of $2$, no $e$ in sight.

Of course you can easily convert any exponential growth or decay law
into a power of $e$ law: just introduce a constant factor in the exponent,
or change the constant that is already there.
For example, $2^x = e^{x \ln 2}$.

The particularly nice thing about $e$ that makes people want to use powers
of $e$ rather than powers of $2$ or $10$ in so many places is not
its exponential growth for large exponents, but the particularly
nice way it behaves for very *small* exponents.

In many places in mathematics and science where the exponent of something
is a variable, that exponent is not necessarily a whole number.
So yes, $2^3 = 2 \times 2 \times 2$ and $e^3 = e \times e \times e$,
but $2^{3/2} = 2 \sqrt 2$ (why?), $2^{1.4} = 2 \sqrt[5]{2^2}$,
and $2^{\sqrt2}$ … that's not so easy to write in other terms,
but it's a number between $2 \sqrt[5]{2^2}$ and $2 \sqrt 2$,
and it is well-defined as the limit of $2^x$ for real numbers $x$
as $x$ approaches $\sqrt2$.

By a *small* exponent I mean something like $0.001$, or better still
$0.000001$, or even $10^{-17}$.
The exponential function of any positive real number $R$ (where $R$ could
be  $2$, $10$, or $289$, not just $e$) has the nice feature that when
$x$ is small, you can write
$$R^x \approx 1 + kx,$$
where $k$ is a constant that depends on $R$ but not on $x$,
and this approximation is very good if $x$ is small enough.
The special thing about $e$ is that for small $x$,
$$e^x \approx 1 + x,$$
that is, the constant $k$ is not needed. (Or you could say $k=1$.)

This special feature of $e$ is intimately related to all kinds of other
special properties it has, such as the fact that $\frac{d}{dx}e^x = e^x$,
or that $\int \frac1x \;dx = \log_e x$, or the way $e$
helps in financial calculations.

This nice property is also a reason why $e^{ix}$, where $x$ is a real number,
can be viewed as a rotation around the center of the complex plane.
For very small $x$, $ix$ is also small in the way that makes this a
good approximation:
$$e^{ix} = 1 + ix.$$

This is a number close to $1$, but a little bit "off to one side" 
from the real-number axis. And the thing is that if we take any
point on the unit circle in the complex plane—the numbers of the
form $\cos\theta + i \sin\theta$—and multiply by $1 + ix$,
for small $x$, the result is approximately
$\cos(\theta + x) + i \sin(\theta + x)$, and if we multiply by $e^{ix}$,
that is the *exact* result: 
$$e^{ix}(\cos\theta + i \sin\theta) = \cos(\theta + x) + i \sin(\theta + x).$$
That is, multiplication by $e^{ix}$ moves a point $x$ radians around
the unit circle.

The unit circle is $2\pi$ radians from $1$ all the way around and back to $1$
again, so $e^{i2\pi} = 1$ Halfway around the circle is $\pi$ radians,
and the point opposite $1$ on the circle is $-1$, so $e^{i\pi} = -1$.

That's it. Multiplication by $e^{ix}$ rotates a complex number $x$ radians
around the center of the plane, and the number $e^{ix}$ itself is the 
point on the complex plane that $1$ gets to if you turn it $x$ radians
around the origin.