# Where did I go wrong in showing that $\left(1+\frac{ix}{n}\right)^n$ goes to $e^{ix}$ as n goes to infinity

Tags: complex-numbers

I was curious in showing that $\left(1+\frac{ix}{n}\right)^n$ goes to $e^{ix}$ as n goes to infinity. I believe this is right as included it is included numerous times in here: [Proof of Euler's formula that doesn't use differentiation?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1327930/proof-of-eulers-formula-that-doesnt-use-differentiation/1328730#1328730). I have:

$e^{ix}=\left(\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n\right)^{ix}=\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{ixn}$ then name ixn as k so we have: $\left(1+\frac{ix}{ixn}\right)^{ixn}=\left(1+\frac{ix}{k}\right)^k$. As per the definition of e, n approaches infinity, and so k (which equals ixn) approaches $i\infty$.

My problem is that k is going to $i\infty$, not just $\infty$ as in the original. Did I make an error or am I misunderstanding something?

Thanks and regards!

**Edit:** My question is where did I make a mistake? I am aware there may not be one and that it may be salvageable, but I don't know how.

Comment: Try taking $ix/n =1/k$

Comment: @Koro if you do that k approaches $-i\infty$, which is not the definition of e. This seems so simple I feel like I am making a huge mistake.

Comment: Then, expand using binomial theorem and then take limit.

Comment: The issue is more basic.  One needs a definition of $w^z$ for complex values of $w$ and $z$.  The definition of $e^{z}$ is given as $e^x \cos(y)+ie^x \sin(y)$ where $x$ and $y$ are the real and imaginary parts of $z$, respectively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$a_n=\left(1+\frac{ix}{n}\right)^n\implies \log(a_n)=n\log\left(1+\frac{ix}{n}\right)$$ Now, by Taylor
$$\log(a_n)=n\left(\frac{i x}{n}+\frac{x^2}{2 n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)\right)=i x+\frac{x^2}{2 n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$
$$a_n=e^{\log(a_n)}=e^{ix}\left(1+\frac{x^2}{2 n}\right)+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$

Comment: What is O? I am sorry I have not come across it before.

Comment: @BenjaminThoburn. the big $O$ notation used for series expansions

Comment: Oh so it's basically just the rest of the series? Thanks I appreciate it!

Comment: I don't quite understand how the last step = e^ix, also how I went wrong in my attempt.

Comment: Ok, sorry about this. I revised the question and title to what I really am curious about asking which is where my attempt went wrong.

Comment: @BenjaminThoburn. Please, do not change the question when answers already came.

Comment: Oops, sorry. I've never done it before so I wasn't aware you weren't supposed to do that. I upvote and accept anyways then :)