# Negative imaginary exponents

Tags: complex-numbers, exponentiation

I was reading this question earlier: [Understanding imaginary exponents](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9770/understanding-imaginary-exponents)

In the answer, the answerer says

> $A^i=x+iy$
>
> Furthermore, we can write $A^{−i}=x−iy$ for the same $x$ and $y$.

Can someone explain to me why this is true? It kind of makes sense to me but how can we make the leap to just negating the imaginary component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**
$$A^i=x+iy$$
$$A^{-i}=\frac{1}{A^{i}}=\frac{1}{x+iy}=\frac{1}{x+iy}\cdot\frac{x-iy}{x-iy}=\frac{x-iy}{x^2+y^2}=x-iy$$

**Note :**
it says
$$|A^i|=1$$

$$|A^i|=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=1$$
$$\Rightarrow x^2+y^2=1$$

Comment: Thanks! Do you know why the note is true? Also, it seems like the answerer in the question I referenced was using this to prove that x^2+y^2=1, isn't this a circular proof?

Comment: @Inbl I think That is clearly mentioned in that answer

Comment: So because |A^i| = 1, we can show x^2+y^2 = 1. We then use that to show that A^-i = x-iy?

Answer (score 2):

If $A>0$ is real, we define $A^z=e^{z\ln A}$. So

$A^i=e^{i\ln A}=\cos(\ln A)+i\sin(\ln A)$
$A^{-i}=e^{-i\ln A}=\cos(-\ln A)+i\sin(-\ln A)=\cos(-\ln A)-i\sin(\ln A)$