# Why does $i^i$ equal more than one number?

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers

As I understand it, $i^i$ returns more than one real number. Why does this happen? When I raise $i$ to $i$, I'm raising a specific number to itself. So why do I get multiple values of this, as if it was, for lack of a better word, some sort of a "function"?

EDIT: My question wasn't "why is $i^i$ real". I know it's real. Furthermore, I know how to calculate $i^i$. I was just looking for intuition as to why this number has multiple values.

Comment: Your wording is unfortunate. A function precisely associates a *single* value to a variable.

Comment: @DietrichBurde  Not a duplicate of that. See the edit.

Comment: This duplicate answers the question nevertheless, although the title only asks for "real". For example, have you read the comment by John Gowers there? It answers your question completely.

Comment: @DietrichBurde It does not. In fact, it says nothing that I didn't know before asking this question. I know how to get these values via Euler's formula (and I stated this); I just wanted an explanation as to why complex numbers behave this way. I find it ridiculous that you guys are superimposing your own idea of what my question should be, rather than what it's. Even after I edited and said I knew how to calculate the values of $i^i$, you're still insisting that a comment calculating the values of $i^i$ answers my question! This is ludicrous!

Comment: I see. Then you should clarify your question. What do you mean by "I was just looking for intuition as to why this number has multiple values." For me it sounds like you simply need to understand "branching", which is already explained very well at this site.

Comment: Do you understand why $e^{i2n\pi} = 1$ for any integer $n$? It's impossible to answer the question the way you want, if you don't tell us what you know.   How much complex analysis have you taken?

Answer (score 11):

There can be multiple values in the same sense that the equation $x^2=1$ yields several square roots ($\pm1$).

But we use the convention that $\sqrt x$ is a positive number, i.e. there is a preferred "branch".

$$\sqrt1=1.$$

Similarly, the complex logarithm has a preferred branch, such that $\log i=i\dfrac\pi2$, allowing us to write

$$i^i:=e^{-\pi/2}.$$

With other branches you would get

$$e^{-\pi/2-2k\pi}.$$

Comment: But in the case $x^2 = 1$ you have a variable $x$. An equivalent situation in the reals in my mind would be something like $2^2$ have more than one value, if that makes sense? I only took a number, and raised it to itself. I don't have any variables!

Comment: @Narco: this is how the square root was defined. Now think about how you would define the number $i^i$ and come back to me.

Comment: Oh, now it sort of makes sense. Thanks, I'm gonna think on this.

Answer (score 6):

To *calculate* $i^i$, you need to go via the logarithm. But there’s a problem with the complex logarithm function, as several of the other answerers have pointed out.

The real logarithm is the inverse of the exponential function $x\mapsto e^x$, which is one-to-one, as you see by looking at its graph. To define the complex logarithm, we would want to make it the inverse of the complex exponential, $z\mapsto e^z$. But this function is *not one-to-one*, as you see from the equation $1=e^0=e^{2\pi i}$, so the complex exponential doesn’t have an inverse. Something radical needs to be done to define *a* logarithm function: as @YvesDaoust makes clear, a choice must be made to do so.

That is to say that there is no *the* logarithm, once you move into the complex world. As my grandmother liked to say, You pays your money and takes your choice. Most of us make a choice leading to $i^i=e^{-\pi/2}$, but another may make a choice leading to another value of $i^i$, and none of us can deny the rightness of such choice.

Answer (score 4):

The other answers focus on the calculation, but your problem might lie in the concepts itself. Reflect on what it means to raise a number by a certain power. For natural numbers, this is for a lack of better words a "natural" operation, that is for $n\in \mathbb{N}$, you can just define

$$x^n := \underbrace{x \cdot x \cdot \ldots \cdot x}_{n-\text{times}}$$

For negative integers, you need to exclude $x=0$, but then you can define $x^{-n} := 1/x^n$. However when you try to extend this to more exponents, things get progressively harder. For rational numbers you can define $x^\frac{p}{q} := \sqrt[q]{x}^p$, but then you need to consider what the $q$-th root of a number means. This you would define as the solution $y$ of $y^q = x$, but this already will not be unique, especially in the complex numbers. The convention here is to use the unique positive real solution, for which however $x$ needs also to be a positive real number.

You can extend this continuously to real numbers, but essentially this is the end of the line. If you want to raise a complex number to a complex power, there is no way to multiply $x$ with itself $i$-times. The only reasonable way is to say that the equation
$$x^a =\exp(\log(x)a)$$
holds for all $x >0$ and $a \in \mathbb{R}$. So you simply try take it as the definition of exponentiation on complex numbers. However then you exactly arrive at the problem that the logarithm is no longer well defined on the complex numbers, as $\exp(2\pi i) = \exp(0) =1$ and thus there is no inverse of the exponential function. So here you will have to take into account all possible solutions $y$ of $x = \exp(y)$ in place of $\log x$, which then leads to the usual calculation.

Answer (score 3):

First you need to realize that this is a multi-valued function.

Let us choose the principal logarithm for convenience. So our argument $\theta$ will lie between $(-\pi,\pi]$.

We then write $\text{a}+\text{b}\cdot i=\text{R}\cdot\exp\left(\theta\cdot i\right)=\exp\left(\ln\left(\text{r}\right)+\theta\cdot i\right)$.

Now, we get $\left(\text{a}+\text{b}\cdot i\right)^{\text{c}+\text{d}\cdot i}=\exp\left(\left(\ln\left(\text{r}\right)+\theta\cdot i\right)\cdot\left(\text{c}+\text{d}\cdot i\right)\right)$. Do the necessary algebraic manipulations in the exponent to get $\exp\left(\left(\text{c}\cdot\ln\left(text{r}\right)-\text{d}\cdot\theta\right)+\left(\text{d}\cdot\ln\left(\text{r}\right)+\text{c}\cdot\theta\right)\cdot i\right)$. You might also want to take a look at the previous question asked on a similar [topic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9770/understanding-imaginary-exponents).

Comment: Probably forgot \ before text in 2 sentence counting from below.

Comment: "First you need to realize that this is a multi-valued function." If I understood this, then I wouldn't even be asking this question.

Comment: @Narco Are you really going to get snarky when someone volunteers their time to help you? Simply look at different answers, read a damned book, or ask someone else for help. Your comment comes off as remarkably ungrateful.

Comment: @DanielW.Farlow My comment was in no way or shape meant to disrespect Jan Eerland, and anything you may have detected from it is most likely the tone with which you have read it. But seeing as you replied to a perfectly innocent comment with such aggression, perhaps you're the one that needs 'help' in the more serious sense of the word?

Answer (score 1):

The expression $i^i$ is just a short form of $\exp(i\log (i))$. We can compute this as soon as we know what $\log(i)$ is. Note that $\log(i)$ is

$$\text{the answer to the question which $z$ satisfies $\exp(z)=i$.}$$

The problem is that there is no single answer. So $\log(i)$ *could* be assinged more than one meaningful value. But we do not do this. Instead we just choose one, i.e. $i\pi/2$. Now the value of $i^i$ is unique. But since this process involves a more or less arbitrary choice I usually do not like to write $a^b$ with anything else than positive real exponents (for general basis).

The same problem appears when computing roots, e.g. $\sqrt{1}$. It is the answer for the question which $z$ satisfies $z^2=1$. And there are two values. We just agreed to always use the positive one.

Answer (score 0):

Remeber that $i$ can be written as $e^{i (\pi/2 + 2\pi k)}$ $\forall k \in \mathbb{N}\cup \{0\}$

thus $i^i = (e^{i(\pi/2 + 2 \pi k})^i = e^{-(\pi/2 + 2\pi k)} = \{{k = 0}\} = e^{- \pi/2}$

But of course you can choose other $k$, if you want a deeper explanation look at Jan Eerlands answer.

Comment: I understand the procedure mechanically, but I've no intuition for your first line.

Comment: Do you know that a complez number $z=a+bi$ can be written as $re^{ix}$ ? @Narco