# What is meaning of imaginary exponent ( e.g. $a^i$ )

Tags: complex-numbers

What is meaning of imaginary exponent e.g. $a^i$?

e.g. $a^b$ can be expressed as $a*a*a ...$ (b times)

how $a^i$ can be interpret ?
Is it possible that $a^i$ is real number ?
I am not able to understand why following hold true even if it has imaginary exponent

Euler's identity $ e^{i\pi} = -1$

Is there any document to explain arithmetic for imaginary exponents
e.g.
How to expand ${(a+b)^i}$

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9770/understanding-imaginary-exponents?rq=1.

Comment: I agreed there are certain rules like fraction mean root (any nth) and negative mean inverse. I am not talking here fractional/negative  exponents